# Virtual Entity with localhost OData service

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-365

I tried to create virtual entity with OData v4 data source.
This guide worked for me with no problems: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lystavlen/virtual-entities

Now I'm trying to create virtual entity with OData v4 data source which is located on localhost. The mappings for the entity and entity fields are done correct.
So, when I open my virtual entity list I got this error:
**Entity could not be retrieved from data source. Please try again or contact your system administrator.**

In Plug-In Trace Log in the newly created record the Exception Details says:
**Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Data.Exceptions.GenericDataAccessException: An OData error occurred.
at Microsoft.Xrm.DataProvider.Odata.V4.Plugins.Client.ExceptionTranslationEdmModelLoader.GetModel(ODataDataSource info, IDictionary`2 httpHeaders) at Microsoft.Xrm.DataProvider.Odata.V4.Plugins.Metadata.ODataMetadataContextFactory.CreateCachedData(ODataDataSource dataSourceInfo, Guid organizationId, IDictionary`2 httpHeaders)**

As I know, in Dynamics 365 there is no requirements for OData services (which are data source for Virtual Entities) to be located **not** in localhost.
Am I missing something? Or there is a way to make it work with localhost OData service?

Comment: is your Dynamics 365 instance on-premise?

Comment: Yes, it's on-premise

Comment: problem is what you consider "localhost". For Dynamics CRM, localhost would be the server where it has been installed (let's call it SERVER1) but localhost is also the local environment for your machine (let's call it CLIENT2). So if you setup a data source pointing to localhost, Dynamics CRM expects to be on SERVER1 and not on CLIENT2 (your machine). If your data source is running not on your machine but on Dynamics CRM server (so SERVER1) then you can use SERVER1 as datasource and not localhost. hope it helps

Comment: Yes, but my OData service is deployed on the same server where my Dynamic CRM is installed (let's call it SERVER1)

Comment: then as I wrote you can try to change the datasource to SERVER1 instead of localhost, that is the only suggestion I have, hope it helps

Comment: Guido, thanks for the help, unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue